# Highlight non-pair rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table where column A and B are a pair: if Column A has data, Column B should too, and vice versa. How could I flag rows where this is not occurring?

[image]

I tried

```
=OR(AND(A1<>"", B1=""), AND(B1<>"", A1=""))
```

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=counta($A1:$B1)=1
```

Comment: when applying to this to range, A3:Q550, and updating your formula to ```=counta($A3:$B3)=1```, it doesn't seem to work on my end

Comment: taking a wild guess that there could be some not TRUE blank cells `=counta(ifna(filter($A3:$B3,$A3:$B3<>"")))=1`

Comment: If I apply it to only columns A and B (neither have formulas), the formula I sent seems to also highlight rows where both A and B are blank for some reason

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following CF rule:

```cpp
=1=COUNTA($A2:$B2)
```

[image]

Comment: when applying to this to range, A3:Q550, and updating your formula to ```=1=COUNTA($A3:$B3)```, it doesn't seem to work on my end

Comment: what formulas do you have in that range?

Comment: If I apply it to only columns A and B (neither have formulas), the formula I sent seems to also highlight rows where both A and B are blank for some reason

Comment: that means that those rows are not really blank. You can verify this by using the `ISBLANK` function. Also consider sharing a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) where you reproduce the issue.